# Numpy float addition with scalar

Tags: python, numpy

I am extracting a csv into a 2d numpy array called x. If I do `print(type(x[i, j]))` the element is a `<class 'numpy.float64'>`

However when I try to add it with an element that is also of the same type, I get this error: `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Here is the context of the code:

```
def load_data():

    x = df[['sqft_living', 'sqft_lot']].astype(float).to_numpy()
    ....
```

````
def compute_gradients(x, y, w, b):
...
    dj_dw = np.zeros((n,))
    dj_db = 0.

    for i in range(m):
        err = (np.dot(x[i], w) + b) - y[i]
        for j in range(n):
            dj_dw[j] += err * x[i,j]
        dj_db += err
...
    ```
````

The error occurs in this line:            `dj_dw[j] += err * x[i,j]`

Not sure why this would happen as Im just adding two elements of the same type

Comment: What is `print(type(err))`, just to be sure?

Comment: `<class 'numpy.float64'>`

Also the error doesnt happen on the first iteration

Comment: Could you add a minimal working example? Don't make us guess what your y, w, b, m, and n are ;)